# $_FILES["sendImageFile"]["name"] return null value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to upload image without page loading, here sendImageFile is the value of file field. Now when I trying to upload any file from `file_upload_to_user.php` but every time `$_FILES["sendImageFile"]["name"]` returns `null` value.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="img_upload_form" id="img_upload_form" action="file_upload_to_user.php">
  <input name="sendImageFile" id="sendImageFile" type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
  <input type="submit" name="photoUploadToSend" id="photoUploadToSend" style="display:none" />                        
</form>
```

JS

```
var frm = $('#img_upload_form');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
  var sendImageFile = document.getElementById("sendImageFile").value;
  var to_hash = "000000000";
  var dataString = 'sendImageFile='+sendImageFile+"&to_hash="+to_hash;
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"file_upload_to_user.php",
    data:dataString,
    cache:false,
    success: function(info) { alert(info);}
  });
}
document.getElementById("sendImageFile").onchange = function change(){ 
  // Upload image
  document.getElementById("photoUploadToSend").click();             
}
```

Comment: post your Html for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a file with ajax then you have to do it with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). And to send a formData with jQuery you need to send two other properties to to disable sending wrong stuff. so it's just easier to use fetch...

```
var form = document.getElementById("img_upload_form")
var fd = new FormData(form)

fetch("file_upload_to_user.php", {method: 'POST', body: fd})
```

To send a formdata with jQuery ajax you have to set this two:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#sendImageFile')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('to_hash',"000000000");

$.ajax({
       url : 'file_upload_to_user.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,//prevent automatic processing
       contentType: false,//do not set any content type header
       success: function(info) { alert(info);}
});
```